# Azure Pipelines maintaining multiple countries / environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines, cicd

We are planning to implement CI/CD for our project. In summary, our setup is the following:

- Code Repository (contains solution and project files)
- Config Repository (contains .config files for different countries)

Aside from having multiple environments, we also have instances in multiple countries. Sample below:

- Country 1

  - Dev
  - QA
  - Prod
- Country 2

  - Dev
  - QA
  - Prod

I understand that Azure Release Pipelines can have multiple **Stages (Dev, QA, Prod)** and **Variables** that can be used for deployment. Then we can have a 1 Release Pipeline for each country.

What I am having difficulty is the **Config Repository**. Sometimes, developers may need to update a specific config file for a Country for a specific environment.

The only solution I can think of is trigger a release pipeline with this again, but just to replace the **Web.config** on IIS in the VM.

However, this is not good, because if developers only update **Code Repository**, any changes from Config Repository will be overwritten.

Any suggestions on how to automate multiple countries / environments with pipelines?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Classic Build Releases or Multi Stage YAML?  Also how are these being hosted on a VM or a PaS solution?

Comment: Multi Stage YAML; we are hosting the web sites / services in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use Azure DevOps Environments to target environment strategy (in your case country and Dev/QA/Prod)

Normal practice shouldn't using repository for .config and any settings files.
you can also consider using [Secure files for Azure Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) or inline script (within your environment deplyonce)

you can start exploring that [Azure Pipeline Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#environment-resources) to understand it and YAML and how can it apply to you Multi-Stage YAML.